# How to remove rows in a Pandas Dataframe with a specific column containing numbers only?

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have this DF:

```
ID     IGName          Date_created
0     BananaMan         09/10/2018
1     Superman247       10/10/2009
2     123456789         08/03/2011
3     Nameless101       07/12/2012
```

I want to be able to **remove** all the rows in the DF where the `IGName` is only numbers.

Like how in this example, row 3 is all numbers. I want to be able to keep the names alphanumeric rows but not the rows with ONLY numerics.

I want the result to look like this:

```
ID     IGName          Date_created
0     BananaMan         09/10/2018
1     Superman247       10/10/2009
3     Nameless101       07/12/2012
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
import pandas as pd


data = [[0, 'BananaMan', '09/10/2018'],
        [1, 'Superman247', '10/10/2009'],
        [2, '123456789', '08/03/2011'],
        [3, 'Nameless101', '07/12/2012']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['ID', 'IGName', 'Date_created'])

df = df[~df['IGName'].str.isnumeric()]

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   ID       IGName Date_created
0   0    BananaMan   09/10/2018
1   1  Superman247   10/10/2009
3   3  Nameless101   07/12/2012
```

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html):

> Check whether all characters in each string in the Series/Index are
>   numeric. Equivalent to str.isnumeric().

Note that this solution assumes the column `'IGName'` is of type string, otherwise you need to cast it to string, doing something like (as mentioned by @RafaelC):

```
df['IGName'] = df['IGName'].astype(str)
```

Comment: This will fail if numbers are actually numbers (int or float type).

Comment: @RafaelC do you mean if the column is of type int or float?

Comment: I mean if you have mixed types in the same column. For example, if in your data, you had `[2, 123456789, '08/03/2011']` instead of `[2, '123456789', '08/03/2011']`

Comment: Does it suffices to cast the column to string first?

Comment: As a matter of fact, yes ;}. Use `.astype(str)`

Comment: @RafaelC Updated the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use `df[...]`:

```
print(df[~df['IGName'].str.isnumeric()])
```

Or:

```
print(df[df['IGName'].str.contains(r'\D+')])
```

Both Output:

```
   ID       IGName Date_created
0   0    BananaMan   09/10/2018
1   1  Superman247   10/10/2009
3   3  Nameless101   07/12/2012
```

If `IGName` has integers do:

```
print(df[pd.to_numeric(df.IGName, errors='coerce').notnull()])
```

Comment: Same observation from above applies here